# XMLHttpRequest send one after another

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How do I send these `XMLHttpRequest`s one at a time?  Right now they are all firing immediately and if there are over six  it locks up the server.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= document.getElementsByName("combobox")[0].value; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/grabdatafromeanotherpage.aspx", true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML + xhr.responseText;
      }
    }
  })(0);
}
```

Comment: changing **.open** to **false** does do what I want, but then I cannot output back to the screen

Comment: You can use fetch with await

Answer (score 0):

Just some untested ideas that may make Javascript gurus scream in agony, but hey, they haven't answered:

You could probably get it to work with (deprecated) synchronous calls, doing something like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= document.getElementsByName("combobox")[0].value; i++) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/grabdatafromeanotherpage.aspx", false);
  xhr.send(); // This will block until a request has been received, no need for a callback function
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML + xhr.responseText;
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use synchronous calls, and you are sure the problem is on the server side (ie. the server can't handle this many almost-simultaneous requests) you could call request number i+1 from the callback of request i, but it would be very messy code.

You could also use the `setTimeout()` function to send the requests at intervals the server *can* handle, 500ms in this example:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= document.getElementsByName("combobox")[0].value; i++) {
  setTimeout(myXHR, 500 * i)
}

function myXHR() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/grabdatafromeanotherpage.aspx", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML + xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

but the order of arrival of the responses would not be guaranteed.

There are probably better/hipper/more modern ways of doing all this with `fetch`/`await`.

If you have full control over the server, I would first try to persuade it somehow to accept and process the quick, successive requests; I find it a bit odd the server can't handle this.